# PowerCLI PowerShell Jobs does not finish

Tags: powershell, powercli

I have the problem that a simple PowerShell Job does not complete. It will always be running.
I am trying the following:

```
$Job = Start-Job -Name "TestJob" -ScriptBlock {param($vcenter,$session) Connect-VIServer -Server $vcenter -Session $session; Get-VM -Name "VMName"} -ArgumentList $global:DefaultVIServer.Name,$global:DefaultVIServer.SessionSecret;
```

Hopefully some of you have an idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of powershell are you using?

Comment: Have you tried capturing the job output? Try piping your code to `Wait-Job | Receive-Job`.

Comment: I found it finally. Thanks for your responses. I will post the solution as an answer :). And to answer your questions: I am using PowerShell Version 5 and Wait-Job didn't finished. The job was always stating "Running". SO had Receive-Job no input.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I cannot explain it but if you write the return of Get-VM in a variable the job will finish normally.

```
$Job = Start-Job -Name "TestJob" -ScriptBlock {param($vcenter,$session) Connect-VIServer -Server $vcenter -Session $session; $t = Get-VM -Name "VMName"} -ArgumentList $global:DefaultVIServer.Name,$global:DefaultVIServer.SessionSecret;
```

Best regards

Comment: Wow, thanks make I would never thought of this solution, if you learned the root cause since you've post this I would like to know ! The better source of knowledge on PowerCli is https://communities.vmware.com/ , a user named LucD is an expert and is still active if anyone need help !